# Change background for only the last 5 bars: A Very Simple Problem I can't crack

Tags: pine-script

I'm new here, and still learning to write pine.  I have a very simple idea I'm trying to code that's been kicking my backside for weeks!

I want the background color for the last five bars to change only a condition has been met in the last 5 bars - the background color change is just to alert me "Hey, this is condition is new - give it a look" - like a visual alert.  I don't want the background to be changed on any of the older bars to the left.  If the condition was met > 6 bars ago I don't want the background changed anywhere on the chart.  I've tried subtracting  60k (milliseconds) * 5 from timenow and it won't work. Any help will be SUPER appreciated!!!
Many thanks,
-Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the exact condition you're considering, but this code will only show the background if the condition is true on one of the last 5 bars:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
bgcolor(high > highest(5)[1] ? color.green : na, show_last = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: OMG!!!  I knew it was a simple answer, but I didn't know it was THAT simple!!  I'd never seen the "show_last" command bgcolor.  
Thank you >>THANK YOU!!!!!!<<
-Daniel